# How to call event handler programatically

Tags: winforms

I have an event handler `CellEndEdit` of `datagridview` in `winforms` application, which runs when i finish write something in `datagridview`. Now i want to call this event also on button click. How can i achieve this? thanks.

Comment: Just add a handler for the button click and call `CellEndEdit` just like any other method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's take a look at a regular event handler. (BTW, you didn't specify C# or VB so I'll use VB)

The name of this subroutine is "Button1_Click" and it takes 2 arguments, of type Object and System.EventArgs.

Normally, an event handler is just called by the system, but there is no reason you can't call the event handler yourself.

The challenge will be if your code in the event handler depends on the sender and event arguments, you'll have a hard time replicating that, but if your code doesn't depend on that, just pass in Nothing or null for each argument.

However, if there is common behaviour, I would define a separate function, and call that function from both event handler, and button click.

Example:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    rgv_CellEndEdit(Nothing, Nothing)
End Sub

Private Sub rgv_CellEndEdit(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As Telerik.WinControls.UI.GridViewCellEventArgs) Handles rgv.CellEndEdit
    FillGridLine()
    If rgv.CurrentCell.ColumnInfo.Name = "ProductId" And rgv.CurrentCell.Value Is Nothing And IsDBNull(rgv.CurrentCell.Value) = True Then
        rgv.CurrentRow = rgv.Rows(rgv.CurrentRow.Index)
        rgv.CurrentColumn = rgv.Columns("ProductId")

    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the use information, but specifically looking into my question. I need a sample code. for example, i have a method or subroutine and have suppose 20 lines of code, between these lines i need to call or run CellEndEdit event. How will i call? sorry for my miss understanding in your previous answer that i think does not fulfill my need, thanks.

Comment: Well post some code then. I gave plenty of information.

Comment: Private Sub rgv_CellEndEdit(sender As System.Object, e As Telerik.WinControls.UI.GridViewCellEventArgs) Handles rgv.CellEndEdit

        FillGridLine()

        If rgv.CurrentCell.ColumnInfo.Name = "ProductId" And rgv.CurrentCell.Value Is Nothing And IsDBNull(rgv.CurrentCell.Value) = True Then
            rgv.CurrentRow = rgv.Rows(rgv.CurrentRow.Index)
            rgv.CurrentColumn = rgv.Columns("ProductId")

Comment: Look at my above code it always run when i finish editing in datagridview. i want to run it on button click or any sub routine, thanks.

Comment: I edited my answer. It would be good to put the code sample in the initial post.